# Functions and range

Tags: functions

> $$ 
>   a \colon  \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\} \to \mathbb{R} \;\text{ defined by }\; a(x)= 6/x \\
>   b \colon  \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R} \;\text{ defined by }\; b(x) = 3x + 1
> $$
>   a) State the range of the functions and if they are "onto".
>   b) State if they are one to one.
>   c) Does the composition $a \circ b$ exist , and if it does give the function, domain, codomain and range.

My work so far:
a) Range of $a$ is all elements of $\mathbb{R}$ except $0$ - not onto because the range is not the same as the codomain. Range of $b$ is all elements of $\mathbb{R}$ - "onto" because the range is  the same as the codomain.

b) Both are one to one because one element of $y$ has one $x$.

c) This is where I'm stuck.

Comment: is the domain for b is $\mathbb Z$, the set of integers? Then  it is not onto and the range is only $\{3n+1| n \in \mathbb Z\}$ .

Comment: nope the domain is R - {0}

Comment: For the second equation? You had written Z.

Comment: sorry, i meant b where the function is $3x+1$.

Comment: For part c) you have not told us which composition the "following composition" is it f(g) or g(f)?

Comment: yep the domain is Z and the co domain is R

Comment: And I also think naming the functions and the questions with same a, b is not a good idea.

Comment: sorry its a o b

Comment: how the mapping b is onto? here 0 has no pre image.

Comment: function b which is 3x + 1 has a range of all the real numbers, the same as the co domain for the function ?

Comment: I edited your question based on your comment.  What have you tried in part (c)?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Tried to work this out and got that it does exist because the range of $b$ is within the domain of f $a$ as there are no range values of $b$ that are 0.

meaning $a(b(x)) = 6/(3x+1)$
domain is Z
co domain is R

Answer (score 0):

You were given that $a: \mathbb{R} - \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by 
$$a(x) = \frac{6}{x}$$
and $b: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $b(x) = 3x + 1$.

The function $a \circ b$ is defined provided that the range of $b$ is contained in the domain of $a$.  Since $3x + 1 \neq 0$ for any integer $x$, the range of $b$ is contained in $\mathbb{R} - \{0\}$, which is the domain of $a$.  Thus, 
$$(a \circ b)(x) = a(b(x)) = a(3x + 1) = \frac{6}{3x + 1}$$
exists, as you concluded.

The domain of $a \circ b$ is $\mathbb{Z}$, the domain of $b$, and its codomain is $\mathbb{R}$, the range of $a$.  The range of $a \circ b$ is the set 
$$R_{a \circ b} = \left\{\frac{6}{3n + 1}~\bigg|~n \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$$